# SharePoint Client Object Model not returning hidden folders in document library

Tags: 2010, document-library, client-object-model

I am using the SharePoint Client Object Model to get information from a SharePoint 2010 document library to be able to delete old htm-files located there. The problem is that these htm-files have hidden "_files"-folders associated to them. I am not able to find these folders using the SharePoint Client Object Model, they just don't show up. I can see them in Windows Explorer using WebDav, but not in SharePoint. They don't get deleted if I just delete the .htm-file.

```
 using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(webUrl))
        {
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            Folder fldr = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeFolderUrl);
            context.Load(fldr);
            context.Load(fldr.Folders);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder folder in fldr.Folders)
            { // no hidden folders found here, only usual folders
                Console.WriteLine(folder.Name);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/findnavish/archive/2011/11/16/some-specific-folder-or-files-not-getting-created-in-sharepoint-thickets.aspx and 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/d6c187ab-3d70-4357-878f-018b9731c161/sharepoint-folder-with-an-underscore-contained-within
you shouldn't be able to upload the folders without getting renamed to *_files_. Are the folders there without the trailing underscore?

If yes, and you somehow really created thickets you won't see them - they won't reveal as they are beliefed as "internal" and never be listed in the OM.
You can still delete them though:

```
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("Documents/google_files")
//while folder.Exist is false the folder could still exist but be hidden
folder.Delete()
```

This won't throw an exception if the folder is not found and delete if it exists.

**Edit, after finding out that you are searching for a method to do this automatically**

You could create an EventReceiver that handles the situation of a file getting deleted and delete the ticket folder to the .htm file accordingly. In the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149.aspx they are canceling the ItemDeleting event, you just have to catch the event occuring in the libraries you want (The event will fire on all items in a web) and delete the thicket.

Just a hint when doing so, Sharepoint Manager (http://spm.codeplex.com) is a great tool that helps you stumbling through the objects on your SharePoint. It has done a great job for me when i was deploying features and custom Receivers into SharePoint.

Comment: I am able to upload the thickets without them getting renamed, using the SharePoint Webservices. This also is the behaviour I want. The issue is that the .htm-files were deleted using the SharePoint website, so if I want to delete the _files I would need to find the folders as I don't know the .htm-file anymore. Our current workaround is a manual webdav-search. This also has the disadvantage of the files being in the recycle bin for 30 days after deletion - the web frontend is not able to delete these 1000s of files from the bin without timing out.